# Reading specific xml data using SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml

I have challenges reading the value of "CMBDESTINOSV" and each of "chk_xxxxx" in the "coberData"  using SimpleXMLElement in the below code snippet.
The code snippet is from an xml response.

I have tried

`$xml->coberData->chk_C0000;
$xml->riskData->CMBDESTINOSV->option->cd[1];`

but nothing was returned. Please help.

```
<root> 
  <riskData label="Risk details"> 
    <CMBDESTINOSV afectaAlPrecio="true" dataName="CMBDESTINOSV" id="CMBDESTINOSV" name="CMBDESTINOSV" type="5" style="width:120" label="Destination" visible="true" maxlength="2" readOnly="false" obligatorio="true" size="3" newLine="false" etiquetaEncima="false" value="-1">-1
      <option>
        <cd>-1</cd>
        <ds/>
      </option>  
      <option>
        <cd>7</cd>
        <ds>05 - Wordlwide Excluding USA &amp; Canada - Wordlwide Excluding USA &amp; Canada</ds>
      </option>  
      <option>
        <cd>10</cd>
        <ds>08 - WORLDWIDE - ALL COUNTRIES</ds>
      </option> 
    </CMBDESTINOSV>
  </riskData>  
  <coberData label="Coverage details"> 
    <chk_C0000 afectaAlPrecio="true" dataName="chk_C0000" id="chk_C0000" name="chk_C0000" type="6" label="BAGAGES" visible="true" onClick="" maxlength="180" readOnly="false" obligatorio="false" size="180" newLine="false" etiquetaEncima="false" value="0"/>  
    <chk_I0000 afectaAlPrecio="true" dataName="chk_I0000" id="chk_I0000" name="chk_I0000" type="6" label="MEDICAL COMPLEMENTARY SERVICES" visible="true" onClick="" maxlength="180" readOnly="true" obligatorio="true" size="180" newLine="false" etiquetaEncima="false" value="1"/>  
    <chk_F0000 afectaAlPrecio="true" dataName="chk_F0000" id="chk_F0000" name="chk_F0000" type="6" label="PERSONAL ACCIDENTS" visible="true" onClick="" maxlength="180" readOnly="true" obligatorio="true" size="180" newLine="false" etiquetaEncima="false" value="1"/>  
    <chk_D0002 afectaAlPrecio="true" dataName="chk_D0002" id="chk_D0002" name="chk_D0002" type="6" label="TRAVEL DELAY" visible="true" onClick="" maxlength="180" readOnly="true" obligatorio="true" size="180" newLine="false" etiquetaEncima="false" value="1"/>  
    <chk_G0000 afectaAlPrecio="true" dataName="chk_G0000" id="chk_G0000" name="chk_G0000" type="6" label="PERSONAL LIABILITY" visible="true" onClick="" maxlength="180" readOnly="true" obligatorio="true" size="180" newLine="false" etiquetaEncima="false" value="1"/>  
    <chk_B0003 afectaAlPrecio="true" dataName="chk_B0003" id="chk_B0003" name="chk_B0003" type="6" label="PERSONAL ASSISTANCE" visible="true" onClick="" maxlength="180" readOnly="true" obligatorio="true" size="180" newLine="false" etiquetaEncima="false" value="1"/>  
    <chk_CAN afectaAlPrecio="true" dataName="chk_CAN" id="chk_CAN" name="chk_CAN" type="6" label="CANCELLATION" visible="true" onClick="" maxlength="180" readOnly="false" obligatorio="false" size="180" newLine="false" etiquetaEncima="false" value="0"/>  
    <chk_U0030 afectaAlPrecio="true" dataName="chk_U0030" id="chk_U0030" name="chk_U0030" type="6" label="ACCIDENTAL DAMAGE" visible="true" onClick="" maxlength="180" readOnly="true" obligatorio="true" size="180" newLine="false" etiquetaEncima="false" value="1"/> 
  </coberData> 
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code worked fine to retrieve the target element, only it prints inner text of the element, which is empty. If you call `asXML()` instead, it will print the correct element :

```
echo $xml->coberData->chk_C0000->asXML();
```

If you meant to access one of the attributes instead, try this way :

```
echo $xml->coberData->chk_C0000->attributes()->afectaAlPrecio;
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/508755)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<chk_C0000 afectaAlPrecio="true" dataName="chk_C0000" id="chk_C0000" name="chk_C0000" type="6" label="BAGAGES" visible="true" onClick="" maxlength="180" readOnly="false" obligatorio="false" size="180" newLine="false" etiquetaEncima="false" value="0"/>

true
```

Comment: $xml->coberData->chk_C0000->attributes()->value; actually worked but $xml->coberData->chk_C0000->asXML(); returned nothing. I can make do with the first option. Any idea on CMBDESTINOSV (riskData)?

Comment: @user1675600 Try to view source of your page (I suspect you can see the XML element there). Use `[1]` indexer on `option` instead of `cd` : `$xml->riskData->CMBDESTINOSV->option[1]->cd;` demo : https://eval.in/508803

Comment: Thanks All. This solved my problem: $xml->coberData->chk_Xxxxx->attributes()->value;
 and  $xml->riskData->CMBDESTINOSV->option[$i]->cd;

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer : [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)